# AWS DynamoDB shows table in "Resource skipped during UpdateRollback" and can´t be deployed again

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-dynamodb, stack, rollback

I deployed a dynamo stack and I had to skip a table due to errors in the table definition. Now I can´t deploy de table again, and when I see the the console, the table (resource) appears as "Resource skipped during UpdateRollback".

Does anybody know how can I deploy again a skipper resource of an stack?

Screenshot that shows the detail in the AWS console:

[image: AWS CONSOLE]

Answer (score 0):

In order to recover from a failed stack update you must  use [`ContinueUpdateRollback`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ContinueUpdateRollback.html).

Then you can make the adjustments that caused that resource to be skipped and re-deploy your updates to bring your stack into a steady state. More details provided here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed/